# Stop Lombok from setting default value for attributes

Tags: java, gson, lombok

I have this Lombok class , when I am creating its object it is setting default values for attributes which is not being set. At places where I am not setting value for httpResponseCode , it is being set as 0. I don't want this variable to take default int value. Is there any way to stop that ?

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StatusInfo {
 public String reasonCode;
 public String result;
 public String description;
 public int httpResponseCode;
 }
```

Comment: that has nothing to do with Lombok. that is how Java works. Please learn the basics before start using tools like Lombok

Comment: And what other value do you expect it to have if you don't set it? By the way, one option is to make `httpResponseCode` an `Integer`, so it will be set to `null` when you don't explicitly give it a value.

Answer (score 3):

It is not related to Lombok. It is as per the default behaviour of primitive data types.

You can use **wrapper classes** instead of primitive data types.

**For example :** Integer for int,Double for double and likewise for other data types.You will get the default value as null instead of 0,0.0 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Its Java behavior. In Java, when an object is created, its properties are initialized with default values based on type:

```
boolean        # with value false
byte           # with value 0
short          # with value 0
char           # with value 0
int            # with value 0
long           # with value 0
float          # with value 0.0
double         # with value 0.0
class types    # with null
```

In Java arrays are also constructed by objects so arrays type parameters are also initialized with null when class object is created.

There is noting to do with Lombok.